# class based view django multiple slugs

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have `cbt generic listview` I want filtering with two slugs. But `slug_url_kwargs` only allows to pass single string. How can i update `slug_url_kwarg` to support multiple slugs? Or what can i do else?

So i have this models and view function

```
class SaityProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=0)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

---

```
class Saity(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey('SaityProfile', null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=gen_slug_page)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sites:website_pages', kwargs={'website_slug': self.url})
```

---

```
class WebsitesProfileList(generic.ListView):
    model = Saity
    slug_field = 'url'
    slug_field_kwargs = 'profile_url'
    template_name = 'saity_ds/websites_profile_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.profile = SaityProfile.objects.get(url=self.kwargs['profile_url'])
        extra_context = {
            'profile': self.profile 
        }
        context =  super(WebsitesProfileList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(extra_context)
        return context
```

My code looks similar like that. I want add new features. I have chosen class based view, and i think it is my mistake, because it is unclear

Comment: The `ListView` doesn't use `slug_url_kwarg` at all. Please [edit] your question to include more information, for example your URL pattern, model, and which fields you want to filter on.

Comment: Thanks, i mean slug on the urlconf, what if i have two slugs and i want filtering based on slugs kwargs?

Comment: You haven't added any more information to your question as I asked. It's much easier to answer your question if it includes your model, names of slug fields, url pattern and anything you have tried for your view so far. When you don't include that information then you're asking us to invent examples. That makes it harder to answer, so you might not get any replies.

Comment: ok, i added my model and view

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set `slug_url_kwarg` at all. Just override `get_queryset` and return the queryset that you want your view to display.

```
class WebsitesProfileList(generic.ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Saity.objects.filter(url=self.kwargs['url'], profile=self.kwargs['profile'])  # You will probably have to change this
    ...
```

Comment: I dream about clean short configuration, i'm scared about super function

Comment: yeah, i know how to add and use filter. I don't like overriding methods, i thought it has clean way

Comment: Overriding `get_queryset` is a [standard technique](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering) in Django generic class based views. The `ListView` does not have a `slug_field_kwarg` option at all, so I cannot think of another approach in this case. There is no need to call `super()` in my example, you are explicitly calling `Saity.objects.filter()` (you could adjust the example to use `super()` if you wanted).