# In Django class based views how I do I use multiple slugs with slug_url_kwarg

Tags: django, django-views

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_url_kwarg),

> The name of the URLConf keyword argument that contains the slug. By default, `slug_url_kwarg` is `'slug'`.

How do I use this for an `UpdateView` where I have two slugs `book_slug` and `chapter_slug`? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39513235/1649171), I can override `get_queryset` method. But is there a way to use multiple slugs with `slug_url_kwarg`? I tried `slug_url_kwarg = ['book_slug', 'chapter_slug']` but it doesn't work.

**Edit:**

I ended up overriding the `get_object` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `slug_url_kwarg` is designed to take a single slug, not multiple.

You can however make your own mixin if you want to be able to do this.

```
class MultiSlugMixin:

    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    slug_url_kwargs = {'slug': 'slug'}  # {slug_field: slug_url_kwarg}
    query_pk_and_slug = False

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
        pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
        slugs = {
            field: self.kwargs[url_kwarg]
            for field, url_kwarg in self.slug_url_kwargs.items()
        }
        if pk is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)

        if slugs and (pk is None or self.query_pk_and_slug):
            queryset = queryset.filter(**slugs)

        if pk is None and not slugs:
            raise AttributeError(
                "Generic detail view %s must be called with either an object "
                "pk or a slug in the URLconf." % self.__class__.__name__
            )

        try:
            obj = queryset.get()
        except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404(_("No %(verbose_name)s found matching the query") %
                          {'verbose_name': queryset.model._meta.verbose_name})
        return obj


class ChapterUpdateView(MultiSlugMixin, UpdateView):

    model = Chapter
    slug_url_kwargs = {'slug': 'chapter_slug', 'book__slug': 'book_slug'}
```